# Div not displaying content from referring page

Tags: ajax, html

Right i have a function which i want to refresh from the database every second. 
The div does refresh but will not recieve the content from the page.

This is my rightmenutimer.php

```
   <?
include "includes/db_connect.php";
$username=$_SESSION["real_name"];
$sql="SELECT * from bankers WHERE name='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row  

$time = time();
$timeleft= $rows['gtatime'];
$last = $timeleft - $time;
$timeleft2=righttime($timeleft);
?>
<?if ($timeleft < "$time"){echo"<font color=green>Available</font>";}else{echo"<b>$timeleft2</b>";}?><?}?>
```

And this is my function/html:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function Ajax(){
var xmlHttp;
    try{    
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    }
    catch (e){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
        }
        catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e){
                alert("No AJAX!?");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()',1000);
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET","rightmenutimers.php",true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout('Ajax()',1000);
}
</script>

<tr><td width="100%">
<table border="1" width="100%" bgcolor="222222">
<tr>
<td width="35%" bgcolor="#171717">GTA</td>
<td width=65%><div id="ReloadThis"><b><a href="_steal_car"><? if ($timeleft < "$time"){?><font color=green>Available</font><?}else{echo"<b>$timeleft2</b>";}?></a></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
```

Can anyone tell me why this wont display, thanks in advance